# How can I send a message to a specific channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    content = message.content
    author = message.author
    await message.channel.send("{}: {}".format(author, content))
```

**I searched for it but I could not find any result. I tried to use client.get_channel("id") it gives typerror i tried to convert it to int but still it didnt work.**
Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO send the retrieved data to specific guild and channel

```
specific_guild = client.get_guild( guild_id )#guild_id must be a integer
specific_channel = specific_guild.get_channel( channel_id )#channel_id must be a integer
await specific_channel.send("{}: {}".format(author, content))
```

To send the retrieved data to a specific channel in the same guild

```
specific_channel = message.guild.get_channel( channel_id )#channel_id must be a integer
await specific_channel.send("{}: {}".format(author, content))
```